# Filtering an array based on presence of string value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know `filter` questions are covered extensivly on SO - but I'm struggling to implement my idea:

I want to filter through my panels & return an array `filteredPanelTabItems` for any that include the layouthint: "tab-view-item" and then the remainder of the array (without "tab-view-item") to another const so I can use it elsewhere, can anyone guide where I'm going wrong?

[image]

The screenshot above shows what's happening in the console when I log:
`panel.panelLinks.links`

```
  const hasTabItemViewHint() => {
    //check for string
  }

  const filteredPanelTabItems = panel.panelLinks.links.filter<Node>(
    (panelLink) => panelLink.(call hasTabItemViewHint function?)
  );
```

Comment: So you want to iterate each element in your Array of Objects and return just elements that have `panel.panelLinks.links[n].LinkModal.layouthint._collections` array that contains "tab-view-item" in it?

Comment: yes exactly, and not sure if possible, but then save the remainder as a different const (that can be consumed elsewhere)?

Answer (score 0):

Consider something like this.

```
var filteredPanelTabItems = $.map(panel.panelLinks.links, function(l, i) {
  if (l.LinkModal.layouthint._collections.indexOf("tab-view-item") >= 0) {
    return l;
  }
});
```

See more: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/